# Using apt-get to install an instance of a web application

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, mediawiki, apt-get, multisite

Is it possible to have many instances of MediaWiki or Wordpress on a web server, installed and automatically upgraded by apt-get? If so, would Ubuntu LTS upgrade with security-only patches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, at least not the way you think. It's not possible to use apt-get to install multiple instances of the same package into different locations.

That said, there are quite some web applications that are designed to be installed once and be run off many different domains. One copy of the source code but configured to run on many virtual hosts, all using different configurations and databases. So, it depends on the package that you want to install.

Answer (score 0):

You could put Your own packages in Your own package repository and add it's address to every server's `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then invoke `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` on all servers to upgrade.

As **Sander Marechal** said, You don't usually need separate copies of the source code for each instance of a service.